# IIS 8.0 and SSL and Subdomains Webapi/Angular

Tags: iis, ssl, web-deployment, asp.net-web-api2, iis-8

I am Developing a web site that has Angular.js based client and Web API 2 server.

Both will be deployed under my website subdoman: "Admin.myDomain.com". 
I would like to have ssl support. (on client and also requests for server)

Thinking that the client will be under Admin.myDomain.com and the Webapi :  Admin.myDomain.com/admin/

In term SSL connection - What should be the best way to deploy this?
What I thought:
1. Connect the IP to the machine - Conenct the SSL work on entire IIS level.
2. Have the angular client side deployed on default web site on IIS.
3. have the web api deployed as subfolder (another applicaation).

will this work?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your certificate specifically for `admin.website.com` or with a wildcard for `*.website.com`. It depends based in your future needs and available budget.

I would suggest to avoid Default Web Site and create a **new WebSite** that accepts only 443 (and link the certificate here) then you put your API running there with something like.

https://admin.website.com/v1/api

and your angular application at:

https://admin.website.com/app